# Facebook Marketing API: Page Backed Instagram Accounts asking for a profile picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, facebook-marketing-api

I preview ads using [AdAccount's `getGeneratePreviews()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/generatepreview/v2.10).
It works great for `AdPreviewAdFormatValues::DESKTOP_FEED_STANDARD`.
When trying `AdPreviewAdFormatValues::INSTAGRAM_STANDARD`, with a real Instagram accounts also works.

But when trying `AdPreviewAdFormatValues::INSTAGRAM_STANDARD` with a [Page Backed Account](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/page/page_backed_instagram_accounts) I get an error message:

> The Instagram account you have selected for your ad does not have a
>   profile photo. Please add a profile photo before creating your ad.

[Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/instagramads#pbia) says it should work fine. Am I doing something wrong? How can I assign a profile photo to an account it doesn't exist?

Thanks

**EDIT**: Like @aprouja1 mention, the facebook page needs a profile picture.

Comment: Does the FB page that is tied to it have a profile pic?